# AutoRecon is taking too long to complete

Tags: scan, enumeration

> AutoRecon is a multi-threaded network reconnaissance tool which
> performs automated enumeration of services. It is intended as a
> time-saving tool for use in CTFs and other penetration testing
> environments (e.g. OSCP).

https://github.com/Tib3rius/AutoRecon

However, I notice that it's taking too long complete. I've tested it on one of my VM a few hours ago and it's not fully completed till now.

It says that `There are 2 tasks still running ...`

Has anyone using this tool before? Did you experience the same problem?

Comment: A little suggestion try to disable nikto and reduce the number of UDP ports to Scan .It can be done in the config.it will reduce the Scan time

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've noticed that it often takes a long time, sometimes just some tools get stuck.

This happens, for example, if the application responds with a redirect to every gobuster request or if it responds to every nikto test. In both cases the scan duration increases dramatically.

You can stop the scan and check in the `results/[target]/scans` folder which task has not been completed or check the errors file `results/[target]/scans/_errors.log` to see if something went wrong